# Is there chess software that allows storage and replay of media annotations?

Tags: software

I would like to annotate my game not only with textual comments like `6. Be5 "This move brings the bishop to a long diagonal"`, but also record such comments with voice. Is there any software package that supports this? I can't find this feature in SCID.

Comment: Are you looking to store such media annotations primarily for yourself, or are you looking for some sort of presentation tool (e.g. for producing/posting video annotations of games)?

Comment: both for myself and for making video clips; as a bonus I'd like for it to aid in converting voice to textual annotations, but is a bit of pie in the sky ..

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with it in a while, but I remember Fritz letting you do that.

Comment: which version did you use?

Comment: I think it was 12

Comment: It is probably `Chessbase` you are referring to (http://www.chessusa.com/chessbase80.html) for the feature of adding multimedia annotations, although it isn't convenient to work with since it does not have the features of a full-fledged audio editor.